# Elasticsearch geo distance query range

Tags: elasticsearch

Hi for a project I am trying to return users from elastic search which are in a `range of 2km to 4km` away from the search user. 
I use the below query
`

```
{ 
  "size": 1000,
  "from": 0,
  "_source": "user_id",
  "query":{

    "bool":{
        "must_not": {
        "terms": {
            "user_id": []
        }
    },
      "filter":[
        {  
          "geo_distance_range":{  
            "from":"2km",
            "to": "4km",
            "location":{  
              "lon":-122.4194,
              "lat":37.7749
            }
          }
        } 
      ]
    }
  }
}`
```

This query is `deleted in elastic search version 6.3` which is the version I am using. 
Can anyone please help me solve this use case in elastic search 6.3? Aggregations only returns the number of users in the range but I want to return complete results of all users in the range.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can't test this, but it seems reasonable that you should be able to combine `must` and `must_not` clauses with `geo_distance`:

```
"query": {
  "bool": {
    "must_not": {
      "terms": {
        "user_id": []
      },
      "geo_distance": {
        "distance": "2km",
        "location": [-122.4194, 37.7749]
      }
    },
    "must": {
      "geo_distance": {
        "distance": "4km",
        "location": [-122.4194, 37.7749]
      }
    }
  }
}
```